# Windows readfile with dynamic buffer

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write a wrapper around Windows file functions, one would read num bytes amount of data from the file and retrun it. For some reason I fail to allocate the memory properly, but I just can't find the reason why:

```
PBYTE Read(int num_bytes, HANDLER hFile){
   PBYTE bBuffer;
   DWORD new_size = sizeof(BYTE)*num_bytes;
   //after the allocation the debugger already displays a 16 char wide placeholder
   bBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(new_size);
   OVERLAPPED o = { 0 };
   o.Offset = 0;
   BOOL bReadDone = ReadFile(hFile, (LPVOID)bBuffer, sizeof(BYTE)*num_bytes, NULL, &o);
   return bBuffer;
}
```

Data gets copied, but the allocated buffer is always too wide and contains extra wierd filler characters. Can sby please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was the file opened with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag?  If you weren't passing `NULL` for the parameter that receives the number of bytes read you could check that, or the return value you're ignoring to see if it was successful.

Comment: @Retired Ninja it is successful, as I mentioned the data gets copied, only I have extra placeholder characters at the end of the string, that I don't understand

Comment: In the code that you've shown you don't check how much was read or if the call succeeded.  You're also apparently trying to do overlapped io which might not give you an immediate result.  Add some error checking and narrow it down.  If the file wasn't opened for overlapped io don't pass that parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"what am I doing wrong?"

sizeof(BYTE) is 1 so you can remove it everywhere and eliminate the redundant new_size variable.

You tagged your question C++ but used malloc to allocate the buffer. Your design makes the caller responsible for freeing the buffer, which is a poor design approach, and even more so by using malloc/free in C++ program. A good C++ solution to this quandry would be to return a 
std::vector.

It is vital that you provide the lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter to ReadFile. Without it you don't know how many bytes were read. And if you don't know how many bytes were read you can't tell the difference between "extra wierd filler characters" and unused memory at the end of the buffer. If the data is characters then character-oriented output routines (and debugger tools) don't know the difference either, since there is no null terminator at the end of the data that was actually read. You could use NumberOfBytesRead to put in a nul terminator so you and the debugger don't read beyond the real data.